# Как не выбирать пустые значения?

Tags: sql

Мой запрос

```
SELECT user_name, business, summa, data, operation_type, 
FROM 
operations WHERE users.id = '1' AND data REGEXP '23.05.2021';
```

Приходит json в виде

```
[{user_name: 'name':, business: '', summa:10000, data: '23.05.2021', operation_type: 'перевод'},
{user_name: 'name':, business: 'автосалон', summa:500000, data: '23.05.2021', operation_type: 'продажа машины'}]
```

Как написать SELECT чтоб не выводились пустые поля? Должно быть так

```
[{user_name: 'name':, summa:10000, data: '23.05.2021', operation_type: 'перевод'},
{user_name: 'name':, business: 'автосалон', summa:500000, data: '23.05.2021', operation_type: 'продажа машины'}]
```

Comment: Показанный запрос возвращает отдельные записи в виде набора значений для отдельных полей. Если к тебе приходит JSON - то что-то где-то его собирает. Что? Где? вот туда и надо обращаться за решением задачи - но это будет не SQL-сервер.

Comment: @Akina, я так понял ТС, выводит результат запроса в json

Comment: @Mostalk Может... и если так - то опять же выводит чем-то и как-то. Вот на этом этапе и надо вмешиваться и изменять поведение на нужное.